# WMI Win32_Directory fail in For-loop with error 800706BE The remote procedure call failed

Tags: for-loop, vbscript, wmi, wmi-query

I search before ask and not find anything applicable to my code. Also what I tried is commented in the code. The error 800706BE (*The remote procedure call failed*) appear in `For..Next` loop and each time break the cycle at varied random amount of iterations. 
What I miss and how to fix that (simple) code?

```
'List All the Folders on a Computer
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
'With objWMIService.Security_
'    .impersonationlevel = 3
'    For I = 1 To 27
'        .Privileges.Add(I)
'    Next
'End With '--------------------------not help at all!
Set colFolders = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Directory")
cnt = 0
'Do Until IsObject(colFolders) '-----not help at all!
'    WScript.Sleep 500
'Loop
On Error Resume Next 'enabled to get extra info from SWbemLastError
For Each objFolder In colFolders
    Wscript.Echo objFolder.Name
    cnt = cnt + 1
'    WScript.Sleep 10 '--------------that make it worst!
Next '---------------the error appear always at this line----------
If Err Then
    Wscript.Echo Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source
    Set lastErr = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLastError")
    Wscript.Echo lastErr.Operation
End If
Wscript.Echo "LastIter.: " & cnt
'-2147023170
'ExecQuery
'LastIter.: 2152 or 1592 or 1314 or 959 ... varied random
```

WBEMTest:

[image]

**P.S.** I did some test with `System Restore` to test one hypothesis and restore a few days back before last Windows security update, and guess what? Now I get different error: **80041033** "Shutting down". It's even more confused as after `Undo Last Restore`, I still get the same **new** error (*Shutting down*). This has not sense.

Comment: Anything in the eventlog? Did you check with [`WBEMtest`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc180684.aspx) and/or [`WMIDiag`](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/02/03/wmidiag-2-1-is-here.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tested with `WBEMTest` and will post screenshot

Comment: Did you try repairing WMI as described [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/8ed26d46-9994-4052-a307-5b071805aea8)?

Comment: Yes, thanks, but likely too late 'cause I play with all suggestions inside scared WMIDiag's report and blow up 
some ugly mess (corrupted apps), and now nothing help any more, still the same repository files missing reported. 
Can I somehow re-install the WMI entirely?

Comment: If repairing fails I believe you'll have to bite the bullet and re-install the system. I'm not aware of any other way.

Comment: Ehh, re-install w'd be very painful.. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: It's very possible that the information you're trying to get after obtaining your list could be obtained in a simpler, less memory intensive way.  Could you tell us why you need a gigantic list of folders?

Comment: Might this be related? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821

Answer (score 0):

Did you try sfc /scannow yet ?
I didn't see mention of which Windows platform this involves.  XP, Vista, 7, 8.x, 10 preview?  32-bit, 64-bit?